# Payment api for transfering funds from Bank accounts to Mpesa(mobile payments)

Tags: android, ios, payment

I'm working on the android and ios app to transfer the users amount to mpesa paybill account and mpesa to mpesa money transfer like the SendWave and Venmo mobile application.

Here i'm accepting only debit card for transfering the funds to the mpesa paybill bank accounts.

i) i'm storing the debit card details for the futrue payments and then transfering the funds to mpesa paybill account.

i didn't find any api regarding this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a public MPesa API as far as I know. The approach I've seen is to contract with a 3rd party "value added services" provider. These groups have a VPN connection to Safaricom for processing bulk payments, and maintain their own commercial API on top of that. For example, [Lipisha](https://lipisha.com/payments/accounts/index.php/app/launch).

Comment: lipisha only works in kenya and that doesn't accept debitcard

Comment: Multi country and debit card funded MPesa is above my pay grade, sorry. The team at Kopo Kopo is the most experienced I know of but I haven't heard of the specific service you're looking for. I believe Lipisha can accept dollars from a foreign account and fund an MPesa wallet -- but only in KE. Would love to hear about it if you figure it out.

Comment: i want to transfer the money within my app by using lipisha web services at the backend but i haven't seen debitcard payment in lipisha rest api sdk

Comment: FWIW, as I understand it multi-country MPesa connectivity can only happen by working with VAS providers country by country. A unified API isn't possible -- Safaricom MPesa in KE is a different backend and interface from Vodacom MPesa in TZ, etc.

Comment: i want to transfer the fund from USA bank holder to kenya mpesa user how can i check with lipisha

Comment: Send them an email. I don't know but seriously doubt they support debit payments out of the box, but you might be able to wrap some other (e.g. EU or US-based) debit service and fund a Lipisha connected bank account, making it look sort-of-seamless to the user. The only systems I've worked with in this space have been a mess of fickle scrapers and proprietary APIs on the backend, but work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Safaricom have just announced release of Mpesa public API:

http://www.safaricom.co.ke/business/m-pesa/API

Answer (score 1):

[Beyonic.com](https://beyonic.com) works across Kenya and Uganda, and soon Tanzania - they have a [public API](https://apidocs.beyonic.com) that will let you send and receive funds to/from MPESA and other mobile wallets across those countries. For the credit/debit card side, check out [Stripe Atlas](https://stripe.com/atlas).

Disclaimer - I work for Beyonic.